# Android - Save Layout content as a Bitmap

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap

I have a screen composited of a Layout. Inside of it I have 3 image a 1 text. I need to share all this on Facebook and/or Twitter.

I have the idea of save all the Layout content as a Bitmap and then share that bitmap

Anybody have any idea of how to do that?

Or maybe some one have other idea of how to do that

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 2):

1. [view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDrawingCacheEnabled%28boolean%29)
2. final Bitmap = [view.getDrawingCache()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache%28%29);
3. [bitmap.compress(....)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29);
4. then upload your files.